Could not create an instance of type com.android.build.api.variant.impl.LibraryVariantBuilderImpl. [Flutter]
I keep getting an error while trying to run a flutter project on android studio, the project runs fine previously on same machine but now raises error after a fresh format of the pc and android studio with other requirement reinstallations.
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':wakelock'.
> Could not create an instance of type com.android.build.api.variant.impl.LibraryVariantBuilderImpl.
   > Namespace not specified. Please specify a namespace in the module's build.gradle file like so:

     android {
         namespace 'com.example.namespace'
     }

     If the package attribute is specified in the source AndroidManifest.xml, it can be migrated automatically to the namespace value in the build.gradle file using the AGP Upgrade Assistant; please refer to https://developer.android.com/studio/build/agp-upgrade-assistant for more information.

This is how the current android/app/build.gradle looks like already there's a namespace but it is still raising same error
plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    id "kotlin-android"
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
}
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

/*def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}*/

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}


android {
    namespace "com.generalomosco.myapp"
    compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.generalomosco.myapp"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    /*implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"*/
}

settings.gradle
pluginManagement {
    def flutterSdkPath = {
        def properties = new Properties()
        file("local.properties").withInputStream { properties.load(it) }
        def flutterSdkPath = properties.getProperty("flutter.sdk")
        assert flutterSdkPath != null, "flutter.sdk not set in local.properties"
        return flutterSdkPath
    }()

    includeBuild("$flutterSdkPath/packages/flutter_tools/gradle")

    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}

plugins {
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-plugin-loader" version "1.0.0"
    id "com.android.application" version "8.0.2" apply false
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "1.7.10" apply false
}

include ":app"


It looks like you updated AGP (android gradle plugin) version. It could happened when you reinstall android studio and leveraged the Upgrade Assistant. Anyway, your AGP now is 8+ version and you have two ways:

Go to your app's android/app/build.gradle file (is also can be build.gradle.kts), find android block and modify it like this:

android {
    namespace = "com.example.myapp" # this should be your namespace from AndroidManifest.xml

... leave rest unchanged...
}


Downgrade your android gradle plugin to 7.* version. Specific steps depends on your configuration, but generally you will got to android/build.gradle, find gradle plugin version and change it.

Good luck!
EDITED:
It is possible that one of packages you're using are obsolete and not ready to be used with modern android-gradle-plugin versions (8+). In this particular case it is wakelock
In this case, you either downgrade your AGP or use another package. Gladly in this case it is possible with wakelock_plus package
EDITED2:
You also can force plugins to use namespaces, for this to work you should add this to your build.gradle. Just make sure that you're adding separate subprojects block:
subprojects {
    afterEvaluate { project ->
        // check only for "com.android.library" to not modify
        // your "app" subproject. All plugins will have "com.android.library" plugin, and only your app "com.android.application"
        // Change your application's namespace in main build.gradle and in main android block.

        if (project.plugins.hasPlugin("com.android.library")) {
            project.android {
                if (namespace == null) {
                    namespace project.group
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


Namespace existing already but still same error

Yeah, my bad, sorry. What interesting, is that error says that project "wakelock" causes issue. Are you using this plugin? https://pub.dev/packages/wakelock

It happens with me but with a different package image_compression_flutter

@OmarYehiaDev image_compression_flutter doesn't have namespace in it's build.gradle, proof. I think you should create issue in package's repo or use another package

Solved replacing the outdated wakelock with wakelock_plus, Thanks @Sameri11

how to replace wakelock to wakelock_plus ? I still kept them showing though

This issue is because namespace is not specified. But if you added and are still facing the issue, like in my case, then you need to add the following code in your project-level (not the one inside the app folder) android/build.gradle in more detail here.
// This should be already in your file
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    // Add this part -------------->
    subprojects {
        afterEvaluate { project ->
            if (project.hasProperty('android')) {
                project.android {
                    if (namespace == null) {
                        namespace project.group
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    // until here

}

It will force all dependencies to use namespace

Not sure if this is an unconventional use case but android projects created via flutter always have two build.gradle files so this isn't super helpful without mentioning this refers to the root level build.gradle, located right within the android folder.

Not only Flutter, but even native Android has two build.gradle files, I have explained briefly on the "here" link.

If used in app/build.gradle.kts add code below to force all dependencies to use namespace.
Caution: this subprojects should place to the first postion than other two subprojects.
subprojects {
    afterEvaluate {
        if (plugins.hasPlugin("com.android.library")) {
            extensions.configure<com.android.build.gradle.LibraryExtension>("android") {
                if (namespace == null) {
                    namespace = group.toString()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


There's a chance that the namespace field is not in the plugin's build.gradle file like so
android {     
 namespace = "com.example.plugin_name"
}     

There will be an error containing the correct namespace if you get the name wrong so just input it when it does

The problem comes from an incompatibility of the package with the new version of gradle.
Before doing the following steps you must delete the .gradle folder located in the android folder.
To correct this you must change the version of project/build.gradle more precisely in: "android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties"
It looks like this:
"distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.6.3-all.zip".
You must then go to the Settings.gradle file and modify the second line in the plugins like this:
id "com.android.application" version "7.3.0" apply false

It would be helpful for us if you could edit your answer so that it's easier to read. Some basic formatting should do it I think

This issue is because namespace is not specified. But if you added and still facing the issue, like in my case, then you need to add the following code in your project-level (not the one inside app folder) android/build.gralde more detail here.
    // This should be already in your file
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

// Add this part ------------>
subprojects {
    afterEvaluate { project ->
        if (project.hasProperty('android')) {
            project.android {
                if (namespace == null) {
                    namespace project.group
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
// Add this part ^^^^^^^^^^^

}
Then
flutter clean

May be encounter with AndroidMenifiest.xml error,
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.

In my case, the AndroidManifes.xml just contains
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
</manifest>

So, my issued solved by adding this,
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    </manifest>

