How to implement HLS and MPEG-TS video player in flutter
So, i have tried using video_player better_player flutter_vlc_player lecle_yoyo_player but none of them worked because of so many errors (even ai couldn't solve).
here's the code:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:video_player/video_player.dart';

class VideoPlayerPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const VideoPlayerPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<VideoPlayerPage> createState() => _VideoPlayerPageState();
}

class _VideoPlayerPageState extends State<VideoPlayerPage> {
  late VideoPlayerController _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = VideoPlayerController.asset('assets/Butterfly-209.mp4');

    _controller.addListener(() {
      setState(() {});
    });
    _controller.setLooping(true);
    _controller.initialize().then((_) => setState(() {}));
    _controller.play();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0),
          ),
          const Text('With assets mp4'),
          Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
            child: AspectRatio(
              aspectRatio: _controller.value.aspectRatio,
              child: Stack(
                alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                children: <Widget>[
                  VideoPlayer(_controller),
                  _ControlsOverlay(controller: _controller),
                  VideoProgressIndicator(_controller, allowScrubbing: true),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class _ControlsOverlay extends StatelessWidget {
  const _ControlsOverlay({required this.controller});

  static const List<Duration> _exampleCaptionOffsets = <Duration>[
    Duration(seconds: -10),
    Duration(seconds: -3),
    Duration(seconds: -1, milliseconds: -500),
    Duration(milliseconds: -250),
    Duration.zero,
    Duration(milliseconds: 250),
    Duration(seconds: 1, milliseconds: 500),
    Duration(seconds: 3),
    Duration(seconds: 10),
  ];
  static const List<double> _examplePlaybackRates = <double>[
    0.25,
    0.5,
    1.0,
    1.5,
    2.0,
    3.0,
    5.0,
    10.0,
  ];

  final VideoPlayerController controller;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        AnimatedSwitcher(
          duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 50),
          reverseDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 200),
          child: controller.value.isPlaying
              ? const SizedBox.shrink()
              : const ColoredBox(
                  color: Colors.black26,
                  child: Center(
                    child: Icon(
                      Icons.play_arrow,
                      color: Colors.white,
                      size: 100.0,
                      semanticLabel: 'Play',
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
        ),
        GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            controller.value.isPlaying ? controller.pause() : controller.play();
          },
        ),
        Align(
          alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
          child: PopupMenuButton<Duration>(
            initialValue: controller.value.captionOffset,
            tooltip: 'Caption Offset',
            onSelected: (Duration delay) {
              controller.setCaptionOffset(delay);
            },
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) {
              return <PopupMenuItem<Duration>>[
                for (final Duration offsetDuration in _exampleCaptionOffsets)
                  PopupMenuItem<Duration>(
                    value: offsetDuration,
                    child: Text('${offsetDuration.inMilliseconds}ms'),
                  )
              ];
            },
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                // Using less vertical padding as the text is also longer
                // horizontally, so it feels like it would need more spacing
                // horizontally (matching the aspect ratio of the video).
                vertical: 12,
                horizontal: 16,
              ),
              child: Text('${controller.value.captionOffset.inMilliseconds}ms'),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Align(
          alignment: Alignment.topRight,
          child: PopupMenuButton<double>(
            initialValue: controller.value.playbackSpeed,
            tooltip: 'Playback speed',
            onSelected: (double speed) {
              controller.setPlaybackSpeed(speed);
            },
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) {
              return <PopupMenuItem<double>>[
                for (final double speed in _examplePlaybackRates)
                  PopupMenuItem<double>(
                    value: speed,
                    child: Text('${speed}x'),
                  )
              ];
            },
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                // Using less vertical padding as the text is also longer
                // horizontally, so it feels like it would need more spacing
                // horizontally (matching the aspect ratio of the video).
                vertical: 12,
                horizontal: 16,
              ),
              child: Text('${controller.value.playbackSpeed}x'),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}


error:
`
Launching lib/main.dart on Realme 8 in debug mode...
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':video_player_android'.


Could not create an instance of type com.android.build.api.variant.impl.LibraryVariantBuilderImpl.
Namespace not specified. Specify a namespace in the module's build file. See https://d.android.com/r/tools/upgrade-assistant/set-namespace for information about setting the namespace.

 If you've specified the package attribute in the source AndroidManifest.xml, you can use the AGP Upgrade Assistant to migrate to the namespace value in the build file. Refer to https://d.android.com/r/tools/upgrade-assistant/agp-upgrade-assistant for general information about using the AGP Upgrade Assistant.


Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.
Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BUILD FAILED in 23s
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (1).
`
I tried the video_player package but i don't know what exactly the error mean.

Check the answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/78744324/2232127 -- if you already have your own namespace set, it's probably the libraries fault. In that case, you can downgrade your gradle version as outlined in one of the answers further down
